# Shifting event times to and from time zones

Tags: java, datetime

I have `getOffseSeconds` method:

```
private int getOffsetSeconds(LocalDateTime localDateTime, ZoneId zoneId) {
    return ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, zoneId).getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
}
```

This method is used in shifted `LocalDateTime` calculation

```
private void shiftEventDateTimeToOriginalZone(EventDto event) {
    event.setStartDateTime(event.getStartDateTime().plusSeconds(
            getOffsetSeconds(event.getStartDateTime(), event.getStartDateTimeZone())));
    event.setEndDateTime(event.getEndDateTime().plusSeconds(
            getOffsetSeconds(event.getEndDateTime(), event.getEndDateTimeZone())));
}
```

Now I need similar method to last one but with small change:

```
private void shiftEventDateTimeToDefaultZone(EventDto event) {
    event.setStartDateTime(event.getStartDateTime().minusSeconds(
            getOffsetSeconds(event.getStartDateTime(), event.getStartDateTimeZone())));
    event.setEndDateTime(event.getEndDateTime().minusSeconds(
            getOffsetSeconds(event.getEndDateTime(), event.getEndDateTimeZone())));
}
```

As you can see, the difference is in using methods: `plusSeconds` and `minusSeconds`. I want replace 2 last methods with another one with same first parameter and second should be lambda operation `plusSecondsOperation` or `minusSecondsOperations`. But I do not know how to do it in Java (Java 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an argument of type:

```
BiFunction<LocalDateTime, Integer, LocalDateTime>
```

To your function that will reflect your need: LocalDateTime *(initial date)*, offset, LocalDateTime *(date that will be returned after applying the function)*. 
The method will look like this:

```
private void shiftEventDateTime(EventDto event, BiFunction<LocalDateTime, Integer, LocalDateTime> f){}
```

To apply the function inside the method you can write it this way:

```
f.apply(event.getStartDateTime(), getOffsetSeconds(event.getStartDateTime(), event.getStartDateTimeZone()));
f.apply(event.getEndDateTime(), getOffsetSeconds(event.getEndDateTime(), event.getEndDateTimeZone()));
```

And when you invoke your method you need to specify the operation itself:

```
shiftEventDateTime(event, LocalDateTime::minusSeconds);
shiftEventDateTime(event, LocalDateTime::plusSeconds);
```

You can choose whatever name for the BiFunction that you like and the one that fits your case the most.